# React not re-rendering child component after updating state var passed as prop

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a simple "pixel art" painting program, just for fun. I've got the painting part working, but I want to have a button that resets the "pixels" of the canvas to their original colors, and I think I must be running into some misunderstanding of how React rendering works.

I've included a much simplified version of the code I'm using below. Here's what I expect to happen when you click the red cell and "paint" it to pink, then click the Reset button:

1. The Grid component's `resetPaint` state var is changed from `false` to `true`
2. This causes a re-render of Grid with `resetPaint` set to `true`
3. Since `resetPaint` is passed to Cell, the props of Cell have now changed, so it re-renders (or at least gets diff'd in the VDOM?)
4. The `if (resetPaint)...` logic in Cell causes it to revert to its default color, which causes it to be re-rendered in the DOM
5. After the Cell renders, we reset resetPaint with `resetPaint && setResetPaint(false)`

Looking at the `console.log` statements, it looks like what's happening is more like this:

1. The Grid component's `resetPaint` state var is changed from `false` to `true`
2. This causes a re-render of Grid with `resetPaint` set to `true`
3. The Cell does *not* re-render
4. We reset resetPaint with `resetPaint && setResetPaint(false)`
5. Grid renders again, this time with `resetPaint` set to `false`
6. *Now* Cell re-renders, but because resetPaint is false, the color is not changed

I assume the second Grid render is due to `setResetPaint(false)`, and while it would be nice if that could be avoided since I know it won't (or shouldn't) change anything, mostly I'm confused about why Cell doesn't re-render after resetPaint is set to true, but then does re-render after it's set to false.

I hope this means I'm on the brink of grokking some aspect of React that I am clearly still not grokking; can someone help get me there?

You can also see and mess with the code in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-forest-jvg1nl?file=/src/App.jsx) (***UPDATED** with working code (see answer)*).

```
import React from 'react';

export const Cell = ({  defaultColor, selectedColorRef, resetPaint}) => {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState(defaultColor)
  const onClick = () => setColor(selectedColorRef.current);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (resetPaint) {
    setColor(defaultColor);
   }
  }, [resetPaint]);
  console.log(`Cell rendering with resetPaint=${resetPaint} and color=${color} (${defaultColor})`); 
  return <div {...{ style: {backgroundColor: color, width:'50px', height:'50px'}, onClick }} />
}

export const Grid = () => {
  // Denotes the selected color in the color palette (palette omitted here for simplicity)
  const selectedColorRef = React.useRef('pink'); 
  // Supposed to trigger a re-render with original color
  const [resetPaint, setResetPaint] = React.useState(false);
  
  console.log(`Grid rendering with resetPaint=${resetPaint}`);
  const grid = (
    <div>
      {/* 
      Normally the drawing "canvas" would be a grid of Cells like this, 
      but we'll just include one for simplicity. 
      */}
      <Cell {...{defaultColor: "red", selectedColorRef, resetPaint}} />
      <button onClick={() => setResetPaint(true)}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  )
    useEffect(() => {
    resetPaint && setResetPaint(false);
  }, [resetPaint]);

  return grid;

}
```

Comment: It would be of help if you could create a codesandbox for this

Comment: Updated the question with a link https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-forest-jvg1nl?file=/src/App.jsx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer! The resetPaint value in the parent was getting re-set before the cells had had time to finish rendering. Moving it to a useEffect like so solved the problem.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    resetPaint && setResetPaint(false);
  }, [resetPaint]);
```

I've updated the codesandbox to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If child gets its `props` from parent you should set stats in `useEffect` if you do somthing like blow it wouldn't updated after props changes

```
export default const Child(props) {
    const [state, setState ] = useState(props.state);
    
}
```

that doesn't worked so you should use structure blow

```
export default const Child(props) {
    const [state, setState ] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
    setState(props.state);
}, [props]);
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with code that uses useEffect like yours, but it has not effect since the issue is that the child element isn't getting re-rendered when I need it to, so useEffect never runs.